# how do I trigger a build from a script with no SC

Tags: buildbot

We are using buildbot with our existing continuous integration system. The artifacts are already built and ready to go and we just want buildbot to execute commands on the slaves. This is working well but how do I trigger a build from a script that is not tied to source control in any way. The same as clicking Force Build from the web gui?

All the triggers seem to expect buildbot to be interacting with source control in some way.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work as follows:

add a change source of type PBChangeSource

```
c['change_source'].append(
        pb.PBChangeSource(port=9999, user='foo', passwd='foo')
)
```

Add a category filter:

```
from buildbot.changes.filter import ChangeFilter

my_filter = ChangeFilter(category='default')
```

add a SingleBranchScheduler with that filter:

```
from buildbot.schedulers.basic  import SingleBranchScheduler

    c['schedulers'] = []
    c['schedulers'].append(
            SingleBranchScheduler(name='waiter', builderNames=["foo"],change_filter=my_filter)
    )
```

From the command line call:

```
 buildbot sendchange -m your.0.0.ip:9999 -a foo:foo -W scriptbot -C default
```